# max date changes with mindate in datepicker

Tags: php, jquery

Here,I have selected max date as 3 week from current date. but actually I don't want to shift max date until current week gets over. I want something like, when current week gets over again max date change to next week end.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        showAnim: "slideDown",
        minDate: 0,
        maxDate: "+3w",
        beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove extra days in the last week by getting the left no of days in the current week.

```js
var now=new Date();
var startDay = 1; //0=sunday, 1=monday etc.
var d = now.getDay(); //get the current day
var weekStart = new Date(now.valueOf() - (d<=0 ? 7-startDay:d-startDay)*86400000); //rewind to start day
var weekEnd = new Date(weekStart.valueOf() + 6*86400000); 

var maxdate=((weekEnd-now)/86400000-1);
if(d!=0 && d<6)
maxdate = 6-maxdate;
else
maxdate = 0; 

 $("#datepicker").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        showAnim: "slideDown",
        minDate: 0,
        //maxDate: "+3w",
        maxDate: "+3w -"+maxdate+"d",//"+3w -2d",
        beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends
    });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css" media="screen" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<input type="text" id="datepicker"/>
```

Comment: Can you tell me how to hide tusday and thursday. what change should i make?

Comment: Check [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pandeyvishal1986/xps3kp76/#&togetherjs=ymvjSnbyH3). Need a Up :)

Comment: I want to upvote it..but i am new to stackoverflow..so my reputation is below 15..and they dont allow me to upvote it..:)

Answer (score 0):

It may help you getting the current date and then applying the max date on it

```
[ https://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/AcbUf/ ]
```